# Peculiar browser caching on Wordpress backend - new post overwrites previous post

Tags: wordpress, caching

I'm experiencing a strange caching problem on our Wordpress site backend (v5.0.8). When creating posts, any post after the first will continue to use the same post ID as the first, therefore overwriting it.

This happens on multiple browsers and devices. I have disabled WP SuperCache and it has had no effect.

This is my reproducible process for observing the issue:

1. In wordpress Posts, or any custom post type, click Add New
2. Enter a title and some data, and click 'save draft' or 'publish' (doesn't
   seem to matter which)
3. Once the post is saved, take note of the post 
   number in the url (ex: /post.php?post=20422)
4. Click Add New again, add a title and data, and click save
5. The post number on the newpost will be the same as the previous

There is one way I can get it to work properly, and that's if, on step 4 after clicking add new, I clear browser cache with a hard refresh (cmd+shift+r) it fixes the issue and will assign it a new post id when I save.

With this information I thought I needed to do something to stop the browser from caching, so I added the following meta tags for admin pages, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE">
```

I don't really know what else to try, or why this is happening in the first place, so I hope someone can offer some insight!

Comment: It's really hard to tell without seeing a URL or your server setup. Have you tried to disable [wp_cache](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#cache)?

Comment: I tried disabling wp_cache but it seems to have no effect. I'm pretty sure it's a browser caching issue for the fact that I can hard refresh and then it works properly.

Comment: The url structure is as simple as:
https://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=20357&action=edit&classic-editor

Comment: Yes, but browser caching issue is leading us back to your server configuration which causing it. I meant if you could share your URL to check my self.

Comment: Was this issue ever resolved? I have a MS site that has the same issues for some users.